# What is the formal definition of tangent hyperplanes?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, partial-derivative

My questions arise from **11.21 DEFINITON** and **11.22 THEOREM** ,both of them presented on *p341 An Introduction To Analysis W.R.Wade 3ed*.

[image]

[image]

**Question 1.**

Considering  **11.21 DEFINITON**,
Let $S:=\begin{cases}
 x^{2}+y^{2}=1  \\ 
 z=1  
\end{cases}$ is a curve in $\mathbf{R}^3.\mathbf{c}=(1,0,1)\in S.$ For every $\mathbf{n}=(x,0,z),x,z\in\mathbf{R}$ satisfy $\mathbf{n}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{c}_k-\mathbf{c}}{||\mathbf{c}_k-\mathbf{c}||}\rightarrow 0$ for all sequences $\mathbf{c}_k\in S\backslash \begin{Bmatrix}
\mathbf{c} 
\end{Bmatrix} $ that converge to $\mathbf{c}.$ Then we leads to planes being tanget to curve ,also we have so much different planes $\Pi_{\mathbf{n} }$ with normal $\mathbf{n}=(x,0,z)$ to be tangent to $S$ at $\mathbf{c}.$ Those aren't quite the same as our's common sense.So what is the formal definition of tangent hyperplanes?

**Question 2.**

Considering  **11.22 THEOREM**,If we find another $\mathbf{p}$ satisfied $\mathbf{p}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{c}_k-(\mathbf{a},f(\mathbf{a}))}{||\mathbf{c}_k-(\mathbf{a},f(\mathbf{a}))||}\rightarrow 0$ for all sequences $\mathbf{c}_k\in S\backslash \begin{Bmatrix}
(\mathbf{a},f(\mathbf{a})) 
\end{Bmatrix} $ that converge to $(\mathbf{a},f(\mathbf{a})),$ How can I prove there must be  a $  \lambda\in \mathbf{R},$such that $\mathbf{p}=\lambda\cdot \mathbf{n},$where $\mathbf{n}=(\nabla f( \mathbf{a}),-1)?$ That is to prove there is an unique hyperplane to be tangent to $S$ at $(\mathbf{a},f(\mathbf{a})).$ I try to make use of the uniqueness of $\nabla f(\mathbf{a})$ to get the uniqueness of hyperplane at $(\mathbf{a},f(\mathbf{a})),$ but I haven't got the answer yet.

Any of your help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think the given definition is fine, but it gives "common sense" results when applied to a surface, not to a curve. As your example shows, a plane tangent to a plane curve does not make much sense.

Comment: @Aretino:I think that what you said is reasonable . Suppose **11.21 DEFINITON** is only applied to hypersurfaces ,In **11.22 THEOREM**,how to prove the uniqueness of hyperplane at $(\mathbf{a},f{(\mathbf{a})})\in S$ ?

Comment: Have you tried to express $z$ by means of its Taylor expansion around $z_0$?